# Docking Vivaldi's Dev Tools

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, developer-tools, vivaldi

As I open the Developer Tools or the JavaScript Console on Chrome/Chromium, I can select a dock side (separate window, bottom or right side).

I started using Vivaldi because I like how customizable it is, however, when it comes to the dev tools, it seems like there is no "Dock site" option and the dev tools is undocked into a separate window.

Is there any way to "dock" the dev tools using Vivaldi?

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do it?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I use Chromium now, using Vivaldi as a web developer is extremely painful.

Answer (score 3):

According to their blog it is now possible to do this in the 1.10 snapshot.

https://vivaldi.com/blog/snapshots/docked-developer-tools-vivaldi-browser-snapshot-1-10-829-3/

Here is the relevant part of the blog post (emphasis my own):

> We have had a long standing request for the ability to dock Developer Tools. Well, wait no longer, **we are introducing this handy feature in our very first 1.10 snapshot**. All of you developers who desperately wanted this, can now breathe a sigh of relief. Of course, if you prefer them undocked, that still works too!

**Edit:** I downloaded 1.10.838.7 and can confirm that it works.